# Deep Copying in Java

Tags: java, constructor, copy, copy-constructor

I have a Java class, Node as follows :

```
class Node
{
    public ArrayList<Node> nbrs;
}
```

Each Node object contains a list of all its neighbours within the ArrayList nbrs, and nothing else.

Now I need to write a function :

```
public Node copy( Node curr )
```

This function should perform a deep copy of the entire graph rooted at curr, and return the equivalent copy for curr.

I tried implementing a copy constructor within the class Node as follows :

```
public Node( Node n )
{
    for( Node curr : n.nbrs )
        n.nbrs.add( new Node( curr  ));
}
```

I now copy the Node n, within my copy function.

But I have found that when the graph contains loops, this code keeps running infinitely.

Any help on how I should overcome this problem.

PS : This is an interview question faced by my friend, so the class Node cannot contain any more variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard trick is to first create all the new nodes and store them in a map (from old nodes to new nodes). Then in a second pass over all the nodes, all the edges are added (by adding to `n.nbrs.add`).

Comment: I like your approach, thank you ! I think this is the simplest to implement moreover, because there is no need for recursion.

Answer (score 2):

If the Node class had a `parent` you'd be able to check for infinite recursion that way. But it doesn't. So you'll need to maintain some state during the clone operation, a `Set` containing the nodes you are currently recursing into. Refuse to descend into a node that is already in the `Set`.

Comment: Thank you, but what will I store in the Set ? I am thinking of the hash values of the Node objects within the original graph. Would that be okay ?

Comment: Why the hash value? For the `Node` given here the hash will be related to the object identity, so why not just be clear and use `Set<Node>`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I could use HashSet for this purpose. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Save the mapping between the old nodes being copied and the new ones in a data structure that allows retrieving elements based on identity (i.e. that retrieves objects iff the `==` operator returns true). An example for this would be the [IdentityHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html). If you create a new node, then save it to the data structure.

Before creating a new `Node` from a previous ony, try to retrieve the node from the data structure. If you have such a node already, then add the retrieved one to the parent. If you don't have such a node, then continue creating one (and add it).

Answer (score 0):

Consider making Node objects immutable. In this case using shared instance will do no harm.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the `Node` class and make it `Serializable`, then you serialize/deserialize the object and get a new graph of objects.

Sample code to illustrate the point:

```
class Node implements Serializable 
{
    public List<Node> nbrs = new ArrayList<Node>();
}

Node n1 = new Node();
Node n2 = new Node();
Node n3 = new Node();
n1.nbrs.add(n2);
n2.nbrs.add(n1);
n2.nbrs.add(n3);
n3.nbrs.add(n2);

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream dos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
dos.writeObject(n1);
dos.writeObject(n2);
dos.writeObject(n3);

ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);

Node n4 = (Node) ois.readObject();
Node n5 = (Node) ois.readObject();
Node n6 = (Node) ois.readObject();
```

At this stage, you'll have a new set of `Node` objects, which correctly reference each other.

Answer (score 0):

There is no base case in the recursion, other than a node with no neighbors.
 
Daniel Earwicker suggested using a `Set` to make sure we don't add the same neighbor twice.  Sounds good, but how can we tell if a node is in the Set?  The default implementation of equals is really just == so no two nodes would be considered equal.  The Set contains method relies on equals to determine if an object has already been added to a set.  We cold add an id field to the node and then implement `boolean equals(Node other)` by checking for id equality. That should make the Set solution work.

Comment: The question rules out adding new fields, but fortunately this is totally unencessary. For two node references `x` and `y`, `x == y` will be `true` if they refer to the same node. That is exactly the test that is required here: we are checking for a node that is its own (possibly indirect) child.

Comment: Do you try your set idea and it worked?  Since we are making copies of nodes, I don't think x == y is what we want for equals.

Comment: From the question: "But I have found that when the graph contains loops, this code keeps running infinitely." i.e. the graph contains at least one node, `N`, which has a list of children, one of which has a list of children (and so on, to some depth...), one of which is `N`. That is `N` (the same object) appears twice in the same tree. That is the problem the OP needed to solve. Another way to think about it it: in your suggestion above, are you going to give every node a unique ID?